# Android - Buffering Lag with VideoView

Tags: android, buffer, delay, android-videoview

I am using VideoView to display a video in my app. The problem is that, once the layout gets created there is lag of almost 10-30 seconds before which the video starts to play. I can see in LogCat that the video is buffering during the lag.

Is there a way I can minimize this lag, or tell MediaPlayer to play the video sooner?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using RTSP Streaming, buffering is the reason of what you have more seamless playback. 
if you are playing an Audio/Video file reduce the bit rate encoding of your files.

Comment: Any way to reduce buffer size?

Comment: While it may be true that buffering adds a delay, lowering the bitrate has no effect on the incredible lag when using eithe rthe VideoView or MediaPlayer classes

Comment: "lowering the bitrate has no effect on the incredible lag" :0, really? have you tested this comparing the same video with different bit rate?

Comment: I did. It does not effect.